# How to produce an Enumerator[T] given Enumerator[Future[T]]

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to get my head around the Iteratee library in Play 2.2.x.  I'm writing a function that generates a stream of data which is expensive to compute.  Here's the basic idea, replacing the expensive to compute part with a square:

```
def expensiveFunction(x: Int): Future[Int] = Future.successful(x * x)

def expensiveRange(start: Int, end: Int): Enumerator[Future[Int]] = {
    Enumerator.enumerate(start to end).map(i => expensiveFunction(i))
}
```

If I call `expensiveRange` I get an `Enumerator[Future[Int]]`, which is not what I want since it seems not to take advantage of the explicit asynchrony of the Iteratee pattern.  It seems I should be able to transform this into an `Enumerator[Int]` which under the covers uses the futures I return instead of creating another layer of `Future`.

Am I right in my thinking that transforming the result to `Enumerator[Int]` is desirable?  If so, what is the idiomatic way to do so?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could convert `Enumerator[Future[Int]]` to `Enumerator[Int]` this way:

```
val enumF = Enumerator((1 to 10).map{Future(_)}:_*) // Enumerator[Future[Int]]

val enum = enumF &> Enumeratee.mapM(identity) // Enumerator[Int]
```

But you don't need this conversion since, as [Travis Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334519/travis-brown)  noted, you could rewrite your method like this:

```
def expensiveRange(start: Int, end: Int): Enumerator[Int] = {
  Enumerator.enumerate(start to end) &> Enumeratee.mapM(expensiveFunction)
}
```

Comment: Why not just plain old `Enumerator.enumerate(1 to 10) &> Enumerator.mapM(expensiveFunction)`?

Comment: @TravisBrown: just because it was my first attempt to use `iteratee` package. Thank you for improvement. I'm not sure it's still my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  In Play 2.2.x I don't see an `Enumerator.mapM` function; I think you meant `Enumeratee.mapM`.  That does seem to work.

Comment: @anelson: yes, `Enumeratee.mapM` is a typo.